# How Can I Split Decimal Value from Integer Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume i have 4.9 value.

I would like to split 4 and .9 ... How can i do it?

I could isolate 4 by using FLOOR(). What about the .9? How can i isolate it?

I'm using t-sql sql server 2005/2008

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
4.9%1
```

You can do modulus divide 1.

Comment: @thyrgle.. isn't 0.9 the remainder of the 4.9/1 integer division ? but the answer is great +1

Comment: @Gaby: Yeah I guess now that I think of it, but I remember someone saying it isn't.

Comment: +1.. for a minute i dint believe it will work till I actually tried it out!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest i can think would be

```
SELECT IntegerPart = cast(4.9 AS int), DecimalPart = 4.9 - cast(4.9 AS int)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Declare @money money

Set @money = 418.75

Select  convert(int,@money - (@money % 1))  as 'LeftPortion'
       ,convert(int, (@money % 1) * 100)    as 'RightPortion'
```

Answer (score 1):

Many mainframe data importation processes (sadly common in the financial industry) require a fixed-width column input file which defines floating point numbers with a few columns for the integer value and a few columns for the decimal value.  I.e. they want the number 4.019 represented as 000401900, where the first 4 chars correspond to the integer and the last 5 correspond to the decimal component.

For this application, you have to do a fair amount of string manipulation, but a good start is to get a query that gives you two fields containing 4 and '01900'.

Parsename() coupled with str() does the trick:

```sql
select integer_part = ltrim(str(4.019,25,0)), decimal_part = parsename(str(4.019, 25, 5),1)
```

str() pads with spaces on the left, so you need to ltrim for the integer.  You might just cast to int here instead.  Parsename just parses out period-delimited string tokens.

Here's a gotcha with this method.  Be careful not to muddle the data type of your decimal_part column:

```
select integer_part = 1, decimal_part = 4
union all
select integer_part = ltrim(str(4.019,25,0)), decimal_part = parsename(str(4.019, 25, 5),1)
```

results in:

```
integer_part    decimal_part
1   4
4   1900
```

Here the intended '01900' became 1900.  Thus:

```
select integer_part = 1, decimal_part = cast(4 as varchar(32))
union all
select integer_part = ltrim(str(4.019,25,0)), decimal_part = parsename(str(4.019, 25, 5),1)
```

results in:

```
integer_part    decimal_part
1   4
4   01900
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @dec decimal(8,2)

Set @dec = 23.98

Select Left(@dec, CharIndex('.',@dec)-1) as 'LeftPortion',
        RIGHT(@Dec, len(@dec) - CharIndex('.',@dec)) as 'RightPortion'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the parsename function.  I think the code below will produce the desired results.
select parsename(4.9,2) gives the 4
select parsename(4.9,1) gives the 9
The output of parsename can be directly used as a number such that
select parsename(4.9,2)* 2 give the vaule 8

Answer (score 0):

Another method is

> select 4.9-CAST(4.9 as int)

Answer (score 0):

A way of converting using PatIndex is as follows

```
declare @val nvarchar(10) = '4.9'
select 
    LEFT(@val,PATINDEX(N'%[.]%', @val)-1) Int_Val,
    RIGHT( @val, len(@val) - PATINDEX(N'%[.]%', @val) + 1) Dec_Val
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different ways but this one looks like the best that worked out for me pretty well.

-- For digits

```
Select  
Left(COLUMN_NAME, Case When CharIndex('.',COLUMN_NAME) = 0 Then 0 Else 
CharIndex('.',COLUMN_NAME)-1 END) as 'LeftPortion',  
RIGHT(COLUMN_NAME, len(COLUMN_NAME) - CharIndex('.',COLUMN_NAME)) as 
'RightPortion'  
From TABLE_NAME
```

--To find Max Lengths

```
Select  
COLUMN_NAME,
  MAX(LEN(Left(COLUMN_NAME, Case When Ind = 0 Then 0 Else Ind-1 END))) as 
LenBeforedecimal,  
MAX(LEN(Right(COLUMN_NAME, LEN(COLUMN_NAME) - Ind))) as afterdecimal  
From  
(Select  
COLUMN_NAME,  
CHARINDEX('.', Cast(COLUMN_NAME as varchar(30))) as Ind  
From TABLE_NAME) a  
Group BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query:
Using the `PARSENAME` function to split the delimited data

```
SELECT value , PARSENAME(value,2) AS int_part,PARSENAME(value,1) AS DECIMAL_ONLY FROM table name
```

example:4.9

Comment: try with this number. 420008631299.3897
incorrectly returns "39" for decimal part. should return "3897"